# React Native: Duplicate items in component state

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-component

I have a two screens in a StackNavigator, one with a FlatList that displays data retrieved from Firestore, and another to add a new data to the database. After returning from the second screen in the stack via navigation.goBack(), the new item should be appended to the list. Instead, the entire state with the new item is being appended to the old state. The database data contains no duplicates and upon refresh, the list contains the correct elements.

I can't tell if I'm misunderstanding the component lifecycle or the query itself so I would appreciate any help.

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {

state = { chatData:[] }


componentDidMount = () => {
  // Make call to Cloud Firestore
  // for the current user, retrieve the chat document associated with each element in the chats id array
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
    doc.data().chats.map((element) => {
      firestore().collection("chats").doc(element).onSnapshot((doc) => {
        this.setState({chatData: [...this.state.chatData, 
          {id: element, subject: doc.data().subject, course: doc.data().course}]})
      })
    });
  })
}
```

[image]
[image]

state after adding a course and returning to the list screen (duplicate element)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my eventual solution. I'm using react-navigation addListener to call the firestore API whenever the first screen is switched to and clearing the state when the second screen is navigated to. I also switched from onSnapshot() to get() for my firestore calls.

```
class Main extends React.Component {

  state = { currentUser: null, chatData:[]}


  componentDidMount = () => {
    console.log('A - component did mount')
    // definitely works
    this.willFocusSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willFocus',
      payload => {
        console.log('A- focus')
        this.readCourseData()
    }) 
    this.willBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
      'willBlur',
      payload => {
        console.log('A- blur')
        this.setState({chatData: []})
      })
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('A - component will unmount')
    this.willFocusSubscription.remove();
    this.willBlurSubscription.remove();
    // Remove the event listener
  }


  readCourseData = () => {
    // Make call to Cloud Firestore
    // for the current user, retrieve the chat document associated with each element in the chats array
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).get().then((doc) => {
      doc.data().chats.map((element) => {
        firestore().collection("chats").doc(element).get().then((doc) => {
          let newArray = [...this.state.chatData, { id: element, subject: doc.data().subject, course: doc.data().course }]
          let uniqueArray = [...new Set(newArray)]
          this.setState({
              chatData: uniqueArray
          })
        })
      });
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

When setting state try to use the prevState callback function. Like so:

```
export default class Main extends React.Component {

state = { chatData:[] }


componentDidMount = () => {
  // Make call to Cloud Firestore
  // for the current user, retrieve the chat document associated with each element in the chats id array
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
    doc.data().chats.map((element) => {
      firestore().collection("chats").doc(element).onSnapshot((doc) => {
        // We use the parameter of the first argument of setState - prevState
        this.setState(prevState => ({chatData: [...prevState.chatData, 
          {id: element, subject: doc.data().subject, course: doc.data().course}]}))
      })
    });
  })
}
```

Because you want to spread the state that was there previously like an accumulator with the new data you're getting from `firestore`. If you do it with `this.state` then you'll be adding it again since it concerns the data that is already in the state and therefore repeated/duplicated. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The items are still being duplicated unfortunately. If I set the state back to empty array in the addButton handler, the list is shown correctly. Unfortunately, if I back out of the screen before adding a new course, the state and therefore the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new array with unique values and assign that to `chatData`

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    firestore().collection("users").doc(user.uid).onSnapshot((doc) => {
        doc.data().chats.map((element) => {
            firestore().collection("chats").doc(element).onSnapshot((doc) => {
                /**
                 * create a new array with unique values
                 */
                let newArray = [...this.state.chatData, { id: element, subject: doc.data().subject, course: doc.data().course }]
                let uniqueArray = [...new Set(newArray)]
                this.setState({
                    chatData: uniqueArray
                })
            })
        });
    })
}
```

Hope this helps you. Feel free for doubts.